# PG::Error: ERROR: relation "reportables" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following migration:

```
  def change
    add_column :reports, :reportable_id, :integer
    add_column :reports, :reportable_type, :integer
  end
```

When I run rake db:migrate, I get the following error:

```
==  AddReportableToReports: migrating =========================================
-- add_column(:reports, :reportable_id, :integer)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "reportables" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "reports" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("reportable_id") REFERENCES "reportables" ("id")
```

This also gives me the same error:

```
change_table :reports do |t|
  t.references :reportable, polymorphic: true
end
```

It says that reportables table doesn't exist. I don't have a reportables table, because this is a polymorphic relation. How can I resolve this?

Comment: reportable_type should be string.

Comment: @test even in the second situation it still fails. The error is regarding reportable_id. It says there is no table called reportables. This is a polymorphic relationship so of course there is no table called reportables. Is it possible to create polymorphic relation in postgresql?

Comment: Is table already created....?

Comment: Have you added `belongs_to :reportable,polymorphic :true` in your model reports

Comment: @test I got it working. I set references to  nil.

Comment: What changes you have done...?

Comment: @test I tried your solution but it didn't work. I posted the solution that worked for me below.

Comment: Both solutions didn't work...?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working when I set references to nil:

```
add_column :reports, :reportable_id, :integer, references: nil
add_column :reports, :reportable_type, :string
```

The REFERENCES keyword is part of a foreign key constraint and it causes the database to require that the value(s) in the specified column(s) of the referencing table are also present in the specified column(s) of the referenced table. That means that it expects there to be a reportables table, which there is not. Apparently, this is specific to PostgreSQL because I never had this problem in MySQL.

Comment: Hmmm...  For me, replacing foreign_key: true with polymorphic: true in the migration  fixed the problem.  Ran into this after running a rails scaffold command for a polymorphic association.  Ironic that the migration will fail out of the box given that lots of Rails users are on Postgres.